# UWP: use 1 MediaSource for several Players

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have some uwp application, where several videos are played simultaneously. I thought it might be a good idea to use 1 media source to improve performance. But I'm not sure why this idea doesn't work.

MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="UWP_OneMediaSourceForSeveralPlayers.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWP_OneMediaSourceForSeveralPlayers"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Yellow" Height="400" Width="200">
        <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="Player1" Height="200" Width="200" />
        <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="Player2" Height="200" Width="200" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Media.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace UWP_OneMediaSourceForSeveralPlayers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(BaseUri, "/Assets/Videos/video.mp4");
            var mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(uri);

            Player1.Source = mediaSource;
            Player2.Source = mediaSource;

            Player1.MediaPlayer.Play();
            Player2.MediaPlayer.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

That's what I see:
[image]

So, looks like the first video is loaded. But not the second...

NOW question: why I can not use 1 media source for 2 players? How to make it work? Or do you have any other idea how to run the same file in several players?

P.S. creating 2 media sources from URI is not a good solution for me, because my app can have a lot (10+) videos running at the same time. If I create a media source for each player it will hurt performance.

Comment: I don't think you ca avoid creating Media Source twice. Even if you set just url to the Media Player internally it creates it's own Media Source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you can actually do here is share a MediaPlayer between the two MediaPlayerElement instance.

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var uri = new Uri(BaseUri, "/Assets/Videos/video.mp4");
    var mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(uri);

    var player = new MediaPlayer
    {
        Source = new MediaPlaybackItem(mediaSource)
    };

    Player1.SetMediaPlayer(player);
    Player2.SetMediaPlayer(player);

    player.Play();
}
```

If you don't require the transport controls from MediaPlayerElement, it's probably better to use MediaPlayerPresenter instead.

Comment: Great! I think that's what I need!